# Как передать строку кода в качестве аргумента функции?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. У меня есть код, где имеются две одинаковые функции, за исключением двух небольших участков. Как можно передать строку кода в цикл for?

```
for (var i=0; i<profilesCount; i++) {  
//сюда нужно вставить строку кода     
box += '<option value="' + friends_data[i].uid + '">' + friends_data[i].first_name + ' ' + friends_data[i].last_name + '</option>';      
}
```

Comment: больше кода и подробностей

Comment: Ну 2 функции у меня. Весь код в них одинаковый, за исключением двух строчек. Хочу все в одну функцию запихать с параметрами. В первой функции цикл такой, какой я привел выше. Во второй функции в месте комментария должна быть строка кода:  
    Data2[i] = {url: data.response[i].photo_medium, uid: data.response[i].uid};

Comment: кто мешает поставить `if`?

    var func = function(arg, flag){
        if(flag){
            console.log(arg);
        }
        console.log(arg);
    }
    func(42); // 42;
    func(42, true); // 42 42

Comment: Эээм.. Не совсем понял. Сохранил допустим я эту строчку кода в переменную. Потом передаю ее в качестве параметра. Как ее в цикле установить? Метка какая-то нужна?

Comment: Ааа. Все дошло. Спасибо. Тогда еще вопросик можно на счет второй строки. Вместо элемента с индекcом one нужно поставить с индексом two.  
    $('#one').html(box);

Comment: я не до конца понял, что вы хотите, но уверен, что можно

Comment: В первой функции стоит $('#one').html(box);  
Во второй стоит $('#two').html(box);  
Как я понимаю тоже с проверкой условия?  
if(flag){  
$('#two').html(box);  
else{  
$('#one').html(box);  
}

Answer (score 2):

чего?

```
var func = function(flag){
   for (var i=0; i<profilesCount; i++) {

       if(flag){
          Data2[i] = {url: data.response[i].photo_medium, uid: data.response[i].uid}; // строка кода
       }
       box += '<option value="' + friends_data[i].uid + '">' + friends_data[i].first_name + ' ' + friends_data[i].last_name + '</option>';      
   }
}
func(); // строка кода не выполняется по очевидным причинам
func(true); // строка кода выполняется по очевидным причинам
```

или так:

```
var func = function(code){
   for (var i=0; i<profilesCount; i++) {

       if(code){
          code()
       }
       box += '<option value="' + friends_data[i].uid + '">' + friends_data[i].first_name + ' ' + friends_data[i].last_name + '</option>';      
   }
}
func(); // строка кода не выполняется по очевидным причинам

func(function(){
    Data2[i] = {url: data.response[i].photo_medium, uid: data.response[i].uid}; // строка кода
}); // строка кода выполняется по очевидным причинам
```

аргумнты функций и названия переменных на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Ну для одной строчки думаю можно с проверкой if-ом.

Answer (score 0):

[Ну например так](http://jsfiddle.net/3bbcE/)

```
var myFunc = function(code){
var box ='';  
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {  
//сюда нужно вставить строку кода     
  if(code !== undefined)eval(code);  
  box += ' - добавили че то еще <br/>';      
}
return box;
```

}

```
document.write(myFunc('box += "Прива мир!"'));
document.write(myFunc('i++;box += i+" теперь цикл меньше"'));
```